# Joomla! SOBI2 edit list categories

Tags: php, joomla

Which file (php, not css) to edit to change the list of categories???
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please be more specific of what you want, and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Aren't they in the database - and don't you edit them by going into 'Components' -> 'SOBI' in the /administrator/ area of your site and editing the Categories?